# Do Azure web sites need to have ASP.NET features?

Tags: asp.net, cdn, visual-studio-2013, iis-express, azure-web-app-service

I created a pretty bare bones web site, with no ASP.NET features, and have published it as an azure web site (http://usamaporama.azurewebsites.net)

Unfortunately, even after hours, all I get from that site, although it appears to be running and published with no errors, is a page that says, "This web site has been successfully created. There's nothing here yet, but ...."

Could it be that Azure is expecting something fancier than my site, and is confused by a package that only contains a couple of references in the HTML to CDNs and a single js file, as well as a single CSS file?

Does it require that a site/app require/reference ASP.NET and/or MVC-specific features, or what?

My site runs fine in local IIS from Visual Studio 2013.

### UPDATE

An article outlining it can be read here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/690045/How-to-Display-and-Hide-Marker-Groups-in-Google-Ma or the source downloaded here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/690045/USAMapORama_Standalone.zip

Comment: what your website contents? how many pages and is there any dlls references? and have you trying package in release mode or debug?

Comment: It is a single page - a google map that I manipulate using the gomap plugin. No DLLs. The only mode available in the dropdown is debug, even though in Web.config I have <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />

Comment: Did you set the default document? What happens if you enter the domain plus the page, i.e. www.mydomain.com/index.html (assuming thats your home page)?

Comment: @E.J.Brennan: Aha, that was it; this gets to it: http://usamaporama.azurewebsites.net/MapORamaHome.html
With my other sites, that's not needed - the base address automatically goes to the default page (in this case the only page). I guess that's the difference between an ASP.NET site and a bare bones site? Make it an answer, and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to set the default document..

http://xamlgeek.net/2010/11/19/start-page-in-azure/